# Python, scrapy: scrape links then iterate over those links to scrape further links

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium, scrapy

I am trying to create a scrapy spider that focuses on a site called weedmaps.com. Weedmaps uses googlemaps API to generate information on dispensaries based on state then regional location information. What I ultimately want to the spider to do is start from the top layer, diver into States, scrape the regional links within those states, go into the regional links one at a time, scrape the dispensary links, and then go into the dispensary links one at a time and scrape specific information regarding those individual dispensaries. Given that the site is dynamic, I have been using selenium to account for javascript. Thanks to help from this site, I have been able to scrape regional links, and dispensary links, but separately. When I try to combine them, the spider only collects the first regional link, and then goes directly into that regional link to collect dispensary information and then it ends. I would also like to somehow create a list of regional links, and dispensary links that will be populated as the spider runs.

Any insights on how to accomplish this would be fantastic. Below is the code for what I have thus far, and I just can't seem to figure this thing out. Thank you in advance!

```
import scrapy
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from scrapybot import __init__

class scrapybot_spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "scrapybot_spider"
    allowed_domains = ['https://weedmaps.com']
    regionlinks = []
    dispensarylinks = []
    start_urls = ["https://weedmaps.com/dispensaries/in/united-states/colorado"]

    #initialize the selenium webdriver via Firefox
    def __init__(self):
        self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()

    #scraping regional links in States
    def parse(self, response):
        self.browser.get('https://weedmaps.com/dispensaries/in/united-states/colorado')
        wait = WebDriverWait(self.browser, 10)
        wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.subregion a.region-ajax-link")))
        for region in self.browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.subregion a.region-ajax-link"):
            time.sleep(5)
            region = region.get_attribute("href")
            self.regionlinks.append(region)
            print regionlinks


    #scraping dispensary links within regional links from above
    def dispensaryparse(self, response):
        global region
        self.browser.get(region)
        wait = WebDriverWait(self.browser, 10)
        wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.dispensary div.name a")))
        for dispensary in self.browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.dispensary div.name a"):
            dispensary = dispensary.get_attribute("href")
            self.dispensarylinks.append(dispensary)
            print dispensary
            return dispensary
```

Comment: Could you try to reduce your problem and write a JSFiddle?

Comment: Although you show the code of your class, you don't show the code that creates an instance of that class. Presumably in the `dispensaryparse()` method you should be iterating over `self.regionlinks` and finding all the dispensaries in that region? Please confirm before I wrote code to answer.

Comment: thanks for the comments! I have never used JSFiddle but I can certainly try and put something up there and attach a link. In regards to the creating an instance of the class, I had used the scrapy start project function and it created a directory of folders. I did not create anything separate for that class function. But yes that is exactly what I would like to do! Preferably store those dispensary links as well so I can then iterate over them again extracting specific dispensary information. Thank you so much to both of you!

Comment: why not use the CrawSpider instead of Spider?